# Dropdown menu inside an iframe adds scroll bar rather than floating at top

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension which would make the post content in linkedin to be summarized Since adding a split button with bootstrap directly in the DOM is pretty complex i have used the iframe approach.

In which i have a created an html file which has a split button which shows the menu in a dropdown.and then injected that in an iframe.

This iframe is added next to the linkedin post button but the problem is since it is in a iframe it takes a default width and height and not making the menu/popover to float above the iframe.

Here is my implementation.

Button.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="./bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="./popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Example split danger button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-popper-placement="top-start">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Injecting this in iframe

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('split-button.html');
iframe.id = 'buttonIframe';
```

Adding the iframe to linkedin post button controls section

```
const shareBoxActionsDiv = document.querySelector('.share-box_actions');
shareBoxActionsDiv.style.display = 'flex';
shareBoxActionsDiv.style.gap = '10px';
shareBoxActionsDiv.insertBefore(iframe, shareBoxActionsDiv.firstChild);
```

This is how it looks

[image]

can someone suggest me how to make the menu to float at top even above the iframe.